# Custom JSON encoder not working with nested model

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to create a custom JSON encoding for a nested Pydantic model. I have simplified the problem to the following example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class SubModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    short_name: str


class TestModel(BaseModel):
    sub_model: SubModel

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {SubModel: lambda s: s.short_name}


model = TestModel(sub_model=SubModel(name="Sub Model", short_name="SM"))

print(model)
print(model.json())
```

I am expecting the final line to output:

```
{"sub_model": "SM"}
```

But instead I am getting the output as if I never even defined my own `json_encoders`:

```
{"sub_model": {"name": "Sub Model", "short_name": "SM"}}
```

How can I correctly define a JSON encoder for another Pydantic model?

Comment: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/2277

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the `json_encoder` you specified. You just need to add `models_as_dict=False` to the `json()` method to override the default dict-like serialization:

```
print(model.json(models_as_dict=False))
```

See https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#serialising-self-reference-or-other-models for the reference.

Comment: Pydantic not having a proper API Reference doc is extremely painful and makes it really difficult to discover features like this. Especially when the user hides information like this behind complicated headings like "Serialising self-reference or other models" that most people aren't likely to read, thinking that it's not relevant in this situation because it's not a "self-reference".

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.
What worked for me is setting the JSON encoders on the global BaseConfig  instead of the class

```py
from pydantic import BaseConfig
BaseConfig.json_encoders = {
    MyClass: lambda v: v.as_str(),
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/2277#issuecomment-764010272